# Javascript Array.map copy without changing original

Tags: javascript

I've noticed that deleting object properties when using `Array.map()` affects the original array, I assume since each iteration's item is still referencing the original array:

```
var objects = [{name: 'a', password: 'x'}, {name: 'b', password: 'x'}];

var clean = objects.map(user => {delete user.password; return user;});

console.log(JSON.stringify(objects));
> [{"name":"a"},{"name":"b"}]
```

Is there a way to use `map` or `filter` without it modifying the original? I can think to loop through each item and create a clone but curious if there's a simpler way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a problem with `map` or `filter`, these methods always return a new array. This is a problem with objects always being passed by reference in Javascript.

Consider the following:

```js
const a = { foo: 1 }
const b = { foo: 2 }

const arr1 = [ a, b ];

const arr2 = arr1.map(v => {
  v.foo = 0;
  return v;
});

console.log(arr1);
console.log(arr2);
console.log(JSON.stringify(arr1) === JSON.stringify(arr2)) // true
```

If you want to create a copy of each object in an array while doing a map you could use the spread operator:

```js
const a = { foo: 1 }
const b = { foo: 2 }

const arr1 = [ a, b ];

const arr2 = arr1.map(v => {
  return {...v, foo: 0};
});

console.log(arr1);
console.log(arr2);
console.log(JSON.stringify(arr1) === JSON.stringify(arr2)) // false
```

It's worth noting that the spread operator is a shallow clone, this means that objects within objects will still be passed by reference.

```js
const c = { foo: 3 }
const a = { foo: 1, biz: c }
const b = { foo: 2, biz: c }

const arr1 = [ a, b, c ];

const arr2 = arr1.map(v => {
  return {...v, foo: 0};
});

console.log(arr1);
console.log(arr2);
console.log(JSON.stringify(arr1) === JSON.stringify(arr2)) // false
```

Answer (score 4):

You can reference everything except `password` with dereferencing. Then use map to build a new object with everything else. This is nice if you have other properties on the object other than `name` and want to include everything except `password`.

```js
var objects = [{name: 'a', password: 'x'}, {name: 'b', password: 'x'}];

var clean = objects.map(({password, ...user}) => user);

console.log(objects);  // untouched

console.log(clean);    // no password
```

Answer (score 1):

You can map over all of the items and return only the name.

```
const objectsWithNames = objects.map(({name}) => ({name}));
```

Comment: Array.map() returns a new array.

Comment: I guess I just need to avoid using `delete` then? and return a new object? If I want to change the values I would need to change them in the new return value too.

Comment: Yeah your use of `delete` is where your problem lies.

Answer (score 0):

The original array isn't being modified, but rather the items in the array (the objects) are. Since javascript objects are passed by reference, when you modify the objects in the new array, the references in the old array show the same modifications.

So, as you said, you can loop through each item and create a clone. Of course, you could perform a deep copy of the entire array too.